# SQL Server 2008 upgrade - compute count

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2016

I am working on upgrading a database from SQL Server 2008 to 2016 and I found the following 2008 SQL that is causing a syntax error at 'compute count'.

How do I resolve this?:

```
select c.name lab_name, d.name creator_name, e.name mod_name, a.mod_dt 
from u_sample_concrete a, lab b, org c, org d, org e, lab_engr f
where a.mod_dt >= 'jan 1 1996 12:00AM' and
a.lab_cd = b.lab_id and b.org_id = c.org_id and
a.create_uid = f.user_id and f.org_id = d.org_id and
a.mod_uid = f.user_id and f.org_id = e.org_id 
order by c.name, d.name, a.mod_dt
compute count(d.name) by c.name, d.name
```

Comment: Along with upgrading to SQL Server 2016, I suggest upgrading the the ***1992*** JOIN Syntax; that's even more overdue than you're version upgrade. Might as well fix your aliasing at the same time, "c" is for "lab" and "c" is the org", but so too so "d" and "e"? "org" doesn't have a single c, d *or* e in it. [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins),[Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: As for `COMPUTE` that was removed in SQL Server 2012, and was replaced by `ROLL UP`.But you have no aggregate functions, so uses it doesn't even make sense to up it. What is this query actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @Larnu I haven't spent the time on this sql to figure out what it is trying to do. Thanks for the Roll Up answer.

Comment: @Larnu Also thanks for the Bad Habits link. that will be helpful.